# Keydown event on contenteditable paragraph

Tags: jquery, contenteditable, keydown

I have used paragraph with content editable property "true" in place of input to achieve the perfect UI.I am trying to change enter key into "password" type so try to achieve the keydown event on the paragraph but facing some problem.

my HTML code is:

```
<div id="usernameInput">
<p id="passwordInput" contenteditable="true" style="width: 100%;text-shadow: none;font-weight: normal; color: #ffffff;" data-ph="Password"></p>
</div>
```

my jquery code is:

```
$('#passwordInput').keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode > 65 && e.keyCode < 90) {
            //code
            $(this).val($(this).val()+'.');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
});
```

But the above code is not working .I could not able to even enter a key.Then I change ".val
" to "text".

the changed code is her :

```
$('#passwordInput').keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode > 48 && e.keyCode < 90 && e.keyCode != 8) {
            //code
            $('#passwordInput').text($('#passwordInput').text()+'.');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
});
```

The above code is working fine but my cursor move in opposite direction.
Please help me to achieve the entered text of my input be password type.

Comment: why did you use a `paragraph` if you want it to be seen as `password`

Comment: can you please fiddle it/

Comment: Hi Kyojimaru,I tried the same thing with div and label.but facing same problem.I tried to make the input box transaprent but that thing is not working even.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that the carpet keeps retracting to the start after you change the contents.

Your task is to move the carret to the end. The least mentally taxing way is to simulate a "down arrow" key press.

```
var x = jQuery.Event("keypress");
x.which = 40;
x.keyCode = 40;
$("#passwordInput").trigger(x);
```

Plug this in before `e.preventDefault();`

This is obviously not the best way to do this but works.